# Why is `for t[1] in iterable` valid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

One of my students wrote a code looking like that (which does not perform what he was expecting at all):

```
t = [1,2,3]
for t[1] in "abcd":
    print("hello")
```

I've never seen this before and was pretty sure it does not compile, but it does and it is modifying  `t[1]` (that is `t[1]` is set to `d` after the loop).

What is the point to allow this syntax ? Is there any use case ? For me the only "acceptable" syntax should be :

```
for <variable_name> in <iterable>:
     ...
```

where `<variable_name>` is an identifier an nothing else.

Comment: The LHS of the `for` can be any sort of assignable, including "complex" stuff like e.g. `for x, *y, z in ...`, so why not `t[1]`?

Comment: (Also, I remember the exact same question from some time ago, but can't find it now... not easy to search for this kind of question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This loop:

```
for x in range(5):
   print(x)
```

Can be translated to:

```
iterator = iter(range(5))
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(x)
```

---

Following the same concept, this loop would be valid too:

```
t = [1,2,3]
for t[1] in 'abcd':
   print('hello')
```

---

```
t = [1,2,3]
iterator = iter('abcd')
while True:
    try:
        t[1] = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print('hello')
```

The end result would be `t == [1, 'd', 3]`

Answer (score 0):

I think Python interprets the iteration syntax as

```
for <container> in <iterable>:
    ...
```

and `t` being a list (aka. a container of containers), `t[1]` is interpreted by Python as a simple container, just like a regular variable.

Comment: Wrong. And FWIW, "I think..." introduces an hypothesis, not a proper technical answer.

Comment: Saying someone is wrong without giving any proof/source is not much better.

Comment: Sorry, I was misguided by your use of the term "container" (which is usually used for things like dicts, lists etc, IOW data types that "contains" other objects). Looks like you meant "variable" or something similar. Note that in Python a variable does not "contain" a value - it's not a memory address, only a name that is bound to a value...